# Pyqt4 processEvents method causing memory leak

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, pyqt, pyqt4

I have some code that should update my gui while calculating showing the progress of the calculation. I already know that it's a bad idea to use processEvents() method to update the GUI. **I should use threads to do so**.
However, I am really curious where do the memory leaks come from? If I run this code with number of while loops big enough (like 10^(6)) the memory usage jumps up to even 1GB. Can you explain it to me?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Calculus:
    def __init__(self):
        print "object created"

    @staticmethod
    def update_progress(self,value,ui_object): 
        ui_object.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Progress: %s %%" % value, None))

        #MEMORY LEAK WHEN UPDATING TOO MUCH (H=0.0001 AND B=1000)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents() #update gui for pyqt



    @staticmethod
    def euler(b,h,progress):
        #progress is an UI object, a label for example.
        actions_done = 0
        actions_number = b * (1./h) #t = t+h. When h = 0.01 we need to perform t=t+h 100(1/h) times to get 1. 
                                    #when t varies from 0 to b, then we need to multiply this 1 * b(end time)
                                    #so we get b * (1/h) as a number of actions to perform

        scale = actions_number * 0.01

        while t <= b:
            actions_done+=1
            progress_value = (actions_done/actions_number)*100

            if (actions_done % scale == 0):
                Calculus.update_progress(None,progress_value, progress)         

            t += h
```